# Which towns to show by current map zoom level?

Tags: google-maps, zooming

How does Google Maps (and other online map service providers) determine that which towns to show by current zoom level? Does it deal with population sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Each zoom level is a set of 256 pixel x 256 pixel tiles.  The tiles are already drawn with the names and locations of towns at an appropriate scale for the zoom level.